# JSON.stringify seemingly abbreviating value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to convert a javascript array to a json string to store in my database, which plots the co-ordinates and such drawn onto a html5 canvas element.

My problem is that with some values, they seem to be being abbreviated or something by the JSON.stringify function. For example, I have a bunch of data that looks something like this:

```
[340,154,"dragstart",6,"db3733"]
```

But sometimes, this will happen to some values (usually when I 'stringify' alot of data):

```
[311,...6,"db3733"]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Where do you see the abbreviated version?

Comment: How do you think so? I'd rather say your output method (e.g. `console.log`) shortens them. Show us your code.

Comment: Oh well I see it when alerting the data. You think it's just that it is shortened when output that way?

Comment: @Sneaksta I'd bet Bergi is right. What browser/platform are you observing this on?

Comment: Haha yep @Bergi, you are correct. It was simply an abbreviation because of direct output. I saved the data to the database via an AJAX request and it's all there correctly. If you wouldn't mind posting your response as an answer, I shall mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` (and the like) do often display ellipsis instead of very long strings or arrays when inspecting an object, yet usually you can expand them (by clicking on `+` or something).